# Play: How to modify data while deserializing Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Here below is a simple case class that holds user information:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class User(
  val username: String,
  val password: String
)
```

... and here is the companion object that provides functionality for serializing/deserializing `User` objects to/from JSON:

```
object User {

  implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
    (__ \ 'username).write[String] ~
    (__ \ 'password).write[String]
  )(unlift(User.unapply))

  implict val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ 'username).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 'password).read[String] // how do I invoke the password hasher here?
  )(User.apply(_, _))
}
```

Let's assume `User` objects should always contain hashed passwords but incoming JSON always provide plaintext... how can I enhance my `Reads` so that it invokes the password hasher while deserializing?

Comment: I hope those cleartext passwords are not coming from some persistent store!

Comment: Oh no ;-) This is just a very, very simple example to explain what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map` method on `Reads`:

```
def doSomething(s: String) = s * 3

case class User(val username: String, val password: String)

object User {
  implicit val userWrites: Writes[User] = (
    (__ \ 'username).write[String] ~
    (__ \ 'password).write[String]
  )(unlift(User.unapply))

  implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ 'username).read[String] ~
    (__ \ 'password).read[String].map(doSomething)
  )(User.apply(_, _))
}
```

And then:

```
scala> Json.parse("""{"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}""").as[User]
res0: User = User(foo,barbarbar)
```

Note, though, that this means that your `Reads` and `Writes` are no longer inverses of each other.